# Get records from current month and next month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a events table and each event has a date, the date that is stored in the table is a php time() stamp. I need to list the events but I only want to list the current months events and next months events.

This is the current SQL query I have

```
    SELECT event_id, event_name, event_date
    FROM events
    ORDER BY event_date DESC
```

Comment: This seems to work but the problem is I have to manually enter the dates for this month and next month
`select event_id, event_date   
from events 
where DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(event_date), "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-09-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL -1 SECOND
order by event_date desc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that works, it took some messing around but it works

```
    select *
      from events
     where DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(event_date), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-09-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL -1 SECOND
     order by event_date desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Month` and `Year` Function

```
SELECT event_id, event_name, event_date
FROM events
where Month(event_date) in (month(now()),month(now())+1)
And Year(event_date) = Year(Now())
ORDER BY event_date DESC
```

Comment: This does not return anything when run, the event_date is in unix epoch time

Comment: To convert the unix time to a date, replace `event_date` with `from_unixtime(event_date)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an index, then do all the transformations on the current date:

```
where event_date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day) and
      event_date < date_add(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day), interval 2 month)
```

MySQL can then use an index (if one exists) on `event_date`.